# Python NameError: Name is not defined Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I'm getting a weird error on some of my scripts. These worked like last week with the same code.

My code:

```
import ipaddress
import csv
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
import operator
import time
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

cnt=1

FMT='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'

start_time=str(time.strftime("%c", time.localtime()))

forpth=r'/home/path/Geo_Assigned'

forfiles=[os.path.join(forpth, fname) for fname in os.listdir(forpth)if fname.startswith('DC')]
forlat=max(forfiles, key=os.path.getmtime)

mskcmlst=['255.255.255.254', '255.255.255.252', '255.255.255.248', '255.255.255.240', '255.255.255.224', '255.255.255.192', '255.255.255.128', '255.255.255.0', '255.255.254.0', '255.255.252.0', '255.255.248.0', '255.255.240.0', '255.255.224.0', '255.255.192.0', '255.255.128.0', '255.255.0.0', '255.254.0.0', '255.252.0.0', '255.248.0.0', '255.240.0.0', '255.224.0.0', '255.192.0.0', '255.128.0.0', '255.0.0.0']


alphlst=[]
WaitList=[]

cmpmask=ipaddress.ip_address('255.255.255.254')

msk32=ipaddress.ip_address('255.255.255.255')

n=0

with open(forlat, newline='') as fin:

    read = DictReader(fin)

    for line in read:
        line['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line['CIDR'])
        line['Mask']=line['CIDR'].netmask
        lwmask=str(line['Mask'])
        alphlst.append(line)
        print(lwmask)



print("This is lowest mask: {}".format(lwmask))

endnum=mskcmlst.index(lwmask)+1

print("This is endnum {}".format(endnum))
```

And I am getting the error:

```
  File "Vtst-linux.py", line 46, in <module>
    print("This is lowest mask: {}".format(lwmask))
NameError: name 'lwmask' is not defined
```

I am getting this error on Linux Ubuntu Python versions 3.4.1 and 3.4.0 but not Windows on with the same Python versions. I have tried this on virtual environments on the Linux server and just running it from the install path with the same results. The input file is basically a bunch of IP networks in CIDR notation.

Any help is appreciated, I am baffled by this and I have tried changing the variable name and other things and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Your code is doomed to fail with empty files, since the `for` loop where you define `lwmask` wont be executed. Are you sure that you are using a non-empty file as input? Does `print(lwmask)` produce output on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `lwmask` is not defined and you try to use it.

This could happen, if the `for line in read:` loop does not contain any item and inner block defining `lwmask` is not executed.

Now you shall research, why it does not contain any line.

Comment: Not certain, but isn't this a scope issue with python 3? I.e. lwmask leaves scope after the for loop, doesn't it?

Comment: @GoingTharn No. A for loop does not create a local scope.

Comment: Yeah, the file was empty. I thought I had checked. Thanks!